# Anyone actually measure the performance impact of using library imports?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, libraries

It's obviously a really nice feature that's pretty standard in programming languages and other cloud computing platforms.

But for some reason GAS discourages the usage of libraries, going as far as stating the following in red font at the top of [the libraries page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries):

> **Warning:** A script that uses a library does not run as quickly as it would if all the code were contained within a single script project. Although libraries can make development and maintenance more convenient, you should use them sparingly in projects where speed is critical. Because of this issue, library use should be limited in add-ons.

Has anyone tried to quantify / test the impact of library imports? What's your experience with when the slow down becomes noticeable?